# Rewrite rule for 2 websites in Sub-Directory and main directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having 2 websites with main directory one and having sub-directory installed another site in it. Having issue for second site( installed in sub-directory), displays error message "This page can't be displayed" or sometimes hosting service provider content.
site 1 :-
path /home/clicknnn/public_html/.htaccess

**BEGIN mainsite**

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^clickcinema.in
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.clickcinema.in/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]

</ifmodule>
```

**END MAINSITE**

Site 2:-
path /home/clicknnn/public_html/movieregister/.htaccess

**BEGIN SECOND SITE**

```
# no indexing
Options -Indexes

# php flag
php_flag register_globals off

# hidden files
    <Files ~ "common.inc.php">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

**END SECOND SITE**

i have second domain pointing documentroot to movieregister directory[image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Does the second site not show at all? Or does it show pages from the first site?

Comment: So what shows when you try to access a page on the second site?

Comment: This page can't be displayed

Comment: @user2573165 do you have a index.php or index.html on the movieregister folder? if not you will get an error.

Comment: i have index.php file in movieregister folder

Comment: Thanks I resolved this problem with hosting provider